# is the only purpose of creating a unique new html tag semantic

Tags: html, semantics, createelement

I have just been introduced to the createElement() method. I am very excited to use it for semantic purposes for a highly specialized player.

I don't really want opinions on if I should or shouldn't do that. What I want to know are other uses for this method.

Comment: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: In a modern web application, there a nearly unlimited applications for this method and all the javascript framework methods that leverage this method.

Comment: @BradChristie Ok. You can add items to an html doc from scratch ie. without having some element there to hold it in the first place. Very cool. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBrant Just list a few.

Comment: @fredsbend You can create an element from scratch.  Have you ever noticed how modern web applications can change the screen around without having to reload the page, creating new elements on the fly in response to user interactions.  None of that would be possible without this method. Or least it would be extremely painful as you would have to have every possible UI combitarion loaded and hidden in the page ready to be shown without such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some of the comments above mentioned things that you might use `createElement` for, there are plenty of source repositories out there that you can use to survey how it's being used.  For instance, you can use GitHub's code search and search for [`.createElement` in Javascript](https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=.createElement&ref=searchresults&type=Code) where you'll find examples of it used to, e.g.:

- insert `script` elements to pages:

  ```
  javascript:(a=(b=document).createElement('script')).src='http://agerst.webs.com/hacks/fb_message.js',b.body.appendChild(a);void(0)
  ```
- create new `div`s on the fly:

  ```
  var FCKToolbarBreak=function(){};FCKToolbarBreak.prototype.Create=function(d){var c=FCKTools.GetElementDocument(d).createElement("div");c.className="TB_Break";c.style.clear=FCKLang.Dir=="rtl"?"left":"right";d.appendChild(c);};
  ```

What I don't see in these examples, however, is instances of creating elements with entirely new types (which is what I'm supposing you mean by using it for semantics).  For instance, I don't see it used to create a elements for marking up, e.g., people:

```xml
<person>
  <personName>…</personName>
  <personAge>…</personAge>
  …
</person>
```

The purpose isn't for creating elements when there's no good element type already out there, it's for manipulating document structure on the fly.

Comment: I actually have used both of those example recently. I, also, actually opted not to create any unique HTML tags in the project I referenced; it seemed like a waste of time after I tried it for a day or two. Nice answer.